# Logstash/grok output sincedb inode number possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've searched for affirmative docs to no avail.

Is it possible to work with sincedb's inode number in logstash.conf?

something like:

```
input { ... file ... }

filter { ... blah blah ... }

mutate {
    add_field => { "sincedb_inode_number" => $SINCEDB_INODE-NUMBER_FOR_CURRENT_MATCH }
}





output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  gelf {
    id => "graylog"
    host => "graylog"
    protocol => "TCP"
    port => 12201
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need to achieve ?

Comment: I'm looking to include the known inode_number of the original file input when outputting the message